# Negative and positive Odd numbers using for loop in python

Tags: python-3.x

I'm new here at this site, so please acknowledge me if I done anything wrong. Anyways, I'm trying to write a simple program that generates all odds numbers from 1 to n using for loop or while loop.

```
n = int(20)

for number in range(1, n + 1):
    if(number % 2 != 0):
        print(format(number), end=" ")
```

But the code above prints only the positive odd numbers. If I change the value of n into a negative number, there is no output. I forgot how to write the code that if n is an even number, the largest generated odd number is n-1. Sorry for my bad English. Thank you guys for the help.

Comment: Change the first number to a negative number. For example (-n + 1)

Comment: Try ```[i for i in range(1, n+1, 2)]``` if you want to start from negative number, try like this ```range(-1, n+1, 2)```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

range takes three parameters start, end, increment

| start | end | increment | output |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| positive | positive | positive | Yes |
| positive | positive | negative | No |
| positive | negative | positive | No |
| positive | negative | negative | Yes |
| negative | positive | positive | Yes |
| negative | positive | negative | No |
| negative | negative | positive | No |
| negative | negative | negative | Yes |

```
n = -int(20)
sign = 1 if n > 0 else -1
for number in range(sign, n + sign, sign):
    if (number % 2 != 0):
        print(format(number), end=" ")
```

Make these changes in the code and it will work for negative and positive numbers.

Comment: I tried this and it works! I'll just remove the negative sign on the int.